# Using Wix Velo Dataset API to hide buttons on my Wix site based on undefined values

Tags: javascript, dataset, velo

I am working on creating a new releases page for my website, where we will use code similar to this to hide `image16` and `image17` if the value cells in my dataset called `appleMusicID` and `spotifyUri` are blank/undefined:

```
  wixData.query("Items")
    .find()
    .then(results => {
      if (results.items.length > 0) {
        const currentItem = results.items[0]; // Assuming you want the first item in the collection

        // Check if the SoundCloud, Apple Music, and Spotify URLs are defined
        const hasSoundCloud = currentItem.soundCloudTrackId && currentItem.soundCloudTrackId !== '';
        const hasAppleMusic = currentItem.appleMusicId && currentItem.appleMusicId !== '';
        const hasSpotify = currentItem.spotifyUri && currentItem.spotifyUri !== '';

        // Update button visibility based on the presence of SoundCloud, Apple Music, and Spotify URLs
        if (hasSoundCloud && hasAppleMusic && hasSpotify) {
          $w('#image17').hide();
          $w('#image16').hide();
        } else {
          $w('#image17').show();
          $w('#image16').show();
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

I have tried messing with a few variable names. I have also tried adding a boolean to our dataset and just use if a boolean called `soundcloudExclusive` is set to true for an item, then hide `image16` and `image17`. I am expecting the top entry to hide the two right buttons, but the bottom entry has all three buttons.